# System.NullReferenceException thrown when using MobileServiceContext in Azure Webjobs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using Mobile Apps in Azure App Service and an webjob is running. The problem is that an error occurs in the webjob.

`` Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at WebJob_CreateThumbnail.Functions.ProcessQueueMessage(Thumbnail thumbnail, TextWriter log) in d:\a\1\s\testdev\WebJob-CreateThumbnail\Functions.cs:line 35 at lambda_method(Closure , Functions , Object[] ) at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidMethodInvoker`1.InvokeAsync(TReflected instance, Object[] arguments) at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`1.<InvokeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__31.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__2c.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__13.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__13.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<TryExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext() ``

Almost all times the error occurs but sometimes the webjob works well without changing any code.
Also, as the error occurs "Functions.cs:line 35" and line 35 is "using (MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext())" in the following code.

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("createthumbnailqueue")]  Thumbnail thumbnail, TextWriter log)
{
    log.WriteLine("userId :{0} + thumbnailURL : {1}", thumbnail.Id, thumbnail.ThumbnailUrl);
    Uri thumbnailUri = new Uri(thumbnail.ThumbnailUrl);
    if (thumbnailUri.Host == _storageURLHost)
    {
            using (MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext())
                {
…
```

The MobileServiceContext is default context in the mobile apps template project and referenced from webjob.
MobileServiceContext is as follows.

```
namespace test.Models
{
    public class MobileServiceContext : DbContext, IMobileServiceContext
    {
        private const string connectionStringName = "Name=MS_TableConnectionString";

        public MobileServiceContext() : base(connectionStringName)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
                new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
                    "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone tell me why sometimes this error occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that thumbnail is not null?

Comment: yeah, it is not null. As I checked parameter, following value is included.(some value is exchanged with 'x' )
{"Id":"facebook972811922757829","ThumbnailUrl":"http://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxx/users/facebook972811922757829/profile/a60bcf5d-f62e-4ad0-8d23-596400125a02.jpg","Width":320,"Height":320,"Type":1}

Comment: According to your description, I couldn't repro your issue. Could you please tell me how you add MobileServiceContext  reference to your webjobs project? Do you just add all the mobile backend project to the webjobs? Besides, I don't suggest you use the context to add record to the mobile service backend. I suggest you could try to use azure webjobs extensions mobile apps binding, which allows you to easily create, read, and update records from an Azure Mobile App. You could refer to this article:https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#azure-mobile-apps

Comment: Here is what I did.  
step1.In Visal Studio 2017, create new solution  with C# mobile apps template project.  
  The project has MobileServiceContext class in the Model folder.
step2.Add webjob project.  
step3.In the webjob, add reference to the mobile apps project so that webjob can use MobileServiceContext.  

That is how I add the MobileServiceContext to webjob. Also, What I would like to do is add url to the record in the DB from the webjob. 
Wasn't that good way? Do you think using webjob extension is better idea?

Comment: I have created a test demo on my computer, it works well. I couldn't repro your issue. Since this error is sometimes happen, so we could just suggest you try another way to test it. In my opinion, I think webjob SDK is a better way to update the mobile record.